# Bitcoin dat file into transactions with Python

Tags: python, transactions, bitcoin

I have a running Bitcoin node which downloads all block .dat files.

Now I would like to parse these files into a Python script and receive only the transaction data.

Afterwards, I am planning to push the data into Google BigQuery for analysis.

Does anyone have a good source for such a python script?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Basically, all you need is to read these `.dat` files with python and send the content to GBQ.

Here is a thread on how to process `.dat` files:
[reading and doing calculation from .dat file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956344/reading-and-doing-calculation-from-dat-file-in-python)

After converting `.bat` into `pandas` data frame, you can use `pandas-gbq` package to save it in Google BigQuery. Documentation: https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/